# What is wrong with it? My programs is'nt drawing a Graph

Tags: c#, oop, graph

What is wrong with it? My programs is not drawing a Graph. But I cannot understand why? Compiler does not show errors. It is my home work. Please , help with it.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Graphics gr = pictureBox1.CreateGraphics();
        int m11, m12, m21, m22, dx, dy, ax, ay;
        int xmin = -5;
        int xmax = 10;
        int ymin = 0;
        int ymax = xmax * xmax;

        ax = pictureBox1.Size.Width / (xmax - xmin);
        ay = pictureBox1.Size.Height / (ymax - ymin);
        m11 = ax;
        m12 = 0;
        m21 = 0;
        m22 = ay;
        dx = -xmin * ax;
        dy = pictureBox1.Size.Height - ay * (-ymin);

        System.Drawing.Drawing2D.Matrix M = new System.Drawing.Drawing2D.Matrix(m11, m12, m21, m22, dx, dy);
        gr.Transform = M;
        int x;
        for (x = xmax; x < xmax; x++)
        {
            System.Drawing.Point p1 = new System.Drawing.Point(x, x * x);
            System.Drawing.Point p2 = new System.Drawing.Point(x + 1, (x + 1) * (x + 1));
            System.Drawing.Pen pen = new System.Drawing.Pen(System.Drawing.Brushes.Black, 0.2F);
            gr.DrawLine(pen, p1, p2);

        }


    }
}
```

I must to drawing func in pictureBox;

Comment: _What is wrong with it?_ This is wrong: _Graphics gr = pictureBox1.CreateGraphics();_  - Winforms graphics basic rule #1 : 

Never use `control.CreateGraphics`! Never try to cache a `Graphics` object! Either draw into a `Bitmap bmp` using a `Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp)` or in the `Paint` event of a control, using the `e.Graphics` parameter..

Comment: Also `for (x = xmax; x < xmax; x++)..` should probably be `for (x = xmin; x < xmax; x++)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your variable x is never instanciated below the max so you need to start it at the min value or your For loop will not work and like Proxy said in his answer you can increase the size of the pen if you want to make it easier to see

```
 int x;
    for (x = xmin; x < xmax; x++)  // set it to the min value at first
    {
        System.Drawing.Point p1 = new System.Drawing.Point(x, x * x);
        System.Drawing.Point p2 = new System.Drawing.Point(x + 1, (x + 1) * (x + 1));
        System.Drawing.Pen pen = new System.Drawing.Pen(System.Drawing.Brushes.Black, 2F); // changed the value here
        gr.DrawLine(pen, p1, p2);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

From what i can see in your for loop you are assigning x the value of max and then checking if x < max which is never true, you even never enter the inside of the for loop.

```
 for (x = xmax; x < xmax; x++)
        {
            System.Drawing.Point p1 = new System.Drawing.Point(x, x * x);
            System.Drawing.Point p2 = new System.Drawing.Point(x + 1, (x + 1) * (x + 1));
            System.Drawing.Pen pen = new System.Drawing.Pen(System.Drawing.Brushes.Black, 0.2F);
            gr.DrawLine(pen, p1, p2);

        }
```

I assume you want to start the x counter from 0 as a staring coordinate on the x axis. Also increase the size of your brush because now it is small so you will not see the line in the box

```
System.Drawing.Pen(System.Drawing.Brushes.Black, 4F);
```